# delete all confirmation php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which previews all the records in a table of my database. I made a button that when it's clicked, all the records of the given table are erased. I just want to add a confirmation message right after the user clicks delete all.

deleteall.php

```
// get the 'id' variable from the URL
$id = $_GET['id'];
$table = $_GET['table'];
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM $table");
```

link (in another php file)

```
echo "<td><a href='../cms/deleteall.php?id=" . "&table=" . $table .  "'>Delete All</a></td>";
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need JavaScript for this. Look into [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm).

Comment: You could use a (PHP) function, but that would require more coding. Take John's comment into consideration, and/or use Ajax. +1 John ;-)

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: use Truncate instead of Delete all)

Comment: @MarcB, it's not injection, it is interface of his service))

Comment: @vp_arth: uh, the query is DIRECTLY using data from $_GET, and in a delete query no less. `http://example.com/cms/deleteall.php?table=users`. "Ooops, sorry about your CMS"

Comment: @MarcB, it is the service, existance of `$_GET['table']` says that here **expected** any table name, may be this is something like phpmyadmin...

Comment: vp_arth: yes, and one would **NEVER** think of modifying a url to see what happens. Please, by all means continue with this bury-your-head-in-the-sand security technique. After your systems get destroyed, don't come crying here asking why.

Comment: `$_GET['table']` is a variable that can be directly manipulated in the URL. Using this in a SQL statement is irresponsible

Comment: @Rossco, all question's code and idea ugly, but we can't do anything here, if author want to allow to client to remove all data in his database... May be it is a sandbox mysql service, and each client has own database?

Comment: @vp_arth Given the nature of op's system and that scenario, i think it to be unlikely.

Comment: @danielsmile, I'm read again... I missed scenario when read first time) >facepalm here< I'm sorry, I always think about all so good, how it's possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the link should be like this:

```
echo "<td><a href='../cms/deleteall.php?id=" . "&table=" . $table .  "' onclick=\"javascript:return confirm('are you sure you want to do this?');\">Delete All</a></td>";
```

So, to make sure, to make a link only go somewhere when the user confirms, use this:

```
<a href="http://www.amazingjokes.com" onclick="javascript:return confirm('do you want to do this?')">test</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

AAAHHH! Are you using GET to - not only change stuff, but - DELETE things from the server? Nonono, that's ***BAD***!

All requests that make changes on the server SHOULD be `POST` requests. Like so:

```
<td><form action="../cms/deleteall.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="table" value="<?=$table?>" />
    <input type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Are you SURE you want to delete everything?');" value="Delete All" />
</form></td>
```

Additionally, VALIDATE! I could very easily change the request to `delete=users` or even `delete=otherdatabase.tablename` just because you haven't validated it, and wipe all the data on your server! Be VERY careful!

Comment: Sidenote: `<?=` hoping OP's open short tags are "on" ;-) always best to use actual `<?php echo...`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Or using PHP 5.4 :p

Comment: can you put this in a php statement because i cant get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a confirmation message when the delete is clicked but before the delete happens, use javascript.

```
function deleteAll(id,table)  
{
    var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete all?")
        if (r==true)
        {
            location.href = "../cms/deleteall.php?id=" + id + "&table=" + table;
        }
}
```

As others have said though, you should be using `$_POST` for this, rather than `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest would be to use javascript.  Modify your link.

```
<a href='../cms/deleteall.php?id=" . "&table=" . $table .  "' onclick="confirm("Are you sure you want to delete all records? ")">Delete All</a>
```

Also a longer method would me you redirect the link to a confirm page first.

```
<a href='../cms/delete_confirm.php?id=" . "&table=" . $table .  "' onclick="confirm("Are you sure you want to delete all records? ")">Delete All</a>
```

delete_confirm.php

```
<?php ?>

<h1>Would you like to delete all records</h1>

    <a href='../cms/deleteall.php?id=".<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?> . "&table=" . <?php echo $_GET['table']  ?> .  "'>Delete All</a>
```

In practice. You'd never use GET methods for deletions or something this serious. Use Post instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust deleteall.php to something like this:

```
// get the 'id' variable from the URL
$id = $_GET['id'];
$table = $_GET['table'];

if(!isset($_GET['confirm'])){
    echo "<a href='../cms/deleteall.php?id=" . $id . "&table=" . $table .  "&confirm'>Confirm Delete</a>";
} else {
    mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM $table");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be of help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmdeletion() {

var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
if (r == true)
  {
     // code that deletes all
  }
else
  {
     // do nothing or handle cancel
  }

}
</script>
```

and you have your php as below:

```
echo "<td><a onClick="confirmdeletion()" href='../cms/deleteall.php?id=" . "&table=" . $table .  "'>Delete All</a></td>";
```

Comment: Nice infinite loop. Try using a different function name ;)

Comment: silly of me @NiettheDarkAbsol, Thanks! anyways! yours is a better solution than mine. +1 for a better solution

Comment: why `r==true` here, and then why not `else if(r == false)` ?

Comment: @vp_arth, what would you like to suggest here? r==true since i have capture the confirm() result in a variable r

Comment: why not `if(r)` ? or even `if(confirm(""))` ?

Comment: well @vp_arth, whats wrong in using a variable and whats wrong in if(r==true)? We can have our own coding styles!